# Flutter get date format from locale to show as hint text

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a form text field for which on tap I'm showing the flutter's datepicker. Currently I'm showing the hint text with hard coded value.

But now I have decided to format the date based on the selected locale and hence I'm passing the local information to ShowDatePicker. How can I show the date format based on the selected locale as hint text in the text field by removing hard coded value?

Ex: [image]

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: TextField(
            label: label,
            hintText: 'MM-dd-yyyy', //Get the format based on selected local to show as hint
            controller: selectedDate,
            onTap: () async {
              final DateTime? pickedDate = await _getSelectedDate(context);
              if (pickedDate != null) {
                selectedDate?.text = DateFormat('MM-dd-yyyy')
                    .format(pickedDate)
                    .toString();
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Future<DateTime?> _getSelectedDate(BuildContext context) {
    return showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        locale: context.currentLocale, // Selected locale being passed to showDatePicker
        initialDate: DateTime.now(),
        firstDate: firstDate,
        lastDate: lastDate,
  }
```

Comment: When user select date you need to show selected date in textfield like this format 'MM-dd-yyyy'?

Comment: @RaviLimbani I want to show the date format as hint text. I just added the sample screenshot in the question. Before used selects the date I want to show what format the date will be displayed. So I want hint text to be shown like 'mm-dd-yyyy'

Comment: Sorry I can't understand what you want. You need to show picked date in 'mm-dd-yyyy' format?

Comment: @RaviLimbani. Sorry that you could not understand, I'm already showing the picked date in mm-dd-yyyy format, I'm also showing the hint text as 'mm-dd-yyyy' by passing that to hintText property of text field. But currently the hint text is hard coded, but the date format will change based on the locale passed to the date picker. So I want to get the date format also from locale so it is not hard coded

Answer (score -1):

1. First of all get the package for it:

   ```
   intl: ^0.17.0
   ```
2. import

   ```
   import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
   ```
3. Define a variable like this:

   ```
   final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('MM-dd-yyyy');
   ```
4. ```
    hintText:"${formatter.format(DateTime.now())}"
   ```
5. This will show date as hint like this:

   ```
    02-22-2022(mm-dd-yyyy)
   ```

Comment: No! formatter.format(DateTime.now()) will format the given datetime according to the expected format (e.g. 02-22-2022) but it will not display the format string.

Comment: /// Return a string representing [date] formatted according to our locale
  /// and internal format.
  String format(DateTime date)

Comment: It will return string as you have defined the formatter. Happy Coding